# jQuery $.data() conditional statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-data

I'm using the html5 "data" attribute on a element, and I want to assign the attribute value to a variable only if it exists and if it's not empty:

`var xxx = $(this).data('what') ? $(this).data('what') : 'default_value';`

but it doesn't work. I always get the default value...

Comment: are you sure that data-what exists at any point?

Comment: Have you outputted the conditional part of the statement to see whether it can actually resolve to true and false? If not, change your conditional so it works.

Comment: ok, the problem was `$(this)` was something else than what I was expecting :) sorry for being dumb :x

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a short circuit is simpler and more efficient:

```
var xxx = $(this).data('what') || 'default_value';
```

But your code should have worked anyway, assuming the data existed (as the commenter noted).

Comment: loooove doing this.  Beat me to the answer :p

Comment: jQuery treats `data-*` attributes as `.data()`.  See @amit_g's demo.

Comment: @Rocket, didn't know that. I removed my caveat. Does it actually store the data as an attribute now? If not, what happens if you update the data but not the attribute?

Comment: So basically it copies the `data-*` values on first access but they are out of sync once changes are made through `$.data`.

Comment: do you guys know what value will have `$(this).data('what');` if there is no data-what attribute?

Comment: it will be `undefined,` but generally it will be falsey, so you can use that code unchanged to return a default value.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like $(this) is not what you expect it to be. Other than that, the statement looks fine. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8eJV3/)

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation:
**.data()**

> The .data() method allows us to attach
>   data of any type to DOM elements in a
>   way that is safe from circular
>   references and therefore from memory
>   leaks.

**.attr()**

> The .attr() method gets the attribute
>   value for only the first element in
>   the matched set.

So what you want is to use the **.attr()** method, like this:

```
var xxx = $(this).attr('data-what') || 'default_value';
```

Comment: jQuery treats `data-*` attributes as `.data()`.  See @amit_g's demo.

Comment: @Rocket: Using `.attr()` for this is faster. Check out http://jsperf.com/data-vs-attr